# Android background service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, background, bind

I'm reading through the docs and the more time I spend I get more confused what's the easiest way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I want to write a simple Service, which starts at button onClick and binds to the activity. And when the activity is closed and started again later (not only restarted!), I want to check whether the service is already running and bind to it. How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: you don't need to check if the service is running. just bind to it, it will be launched if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In that Scenario I think you only need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
         hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To perform actual binding of services to activities in android, you'll need to extend the Service class and bind the service to your activity ( and possibly use Android's AIDL to perform communication between the activity & service).   However, in your example, is sounds like you could get away with just using a separate thread within your activity.  Use either a runnable or an AsyncTask.    Once the user clicks the button that fire's the onClick, set a static boolean within your application to true.  Then, upon re-entry into the activity, simply check that boolean for true and, if true, fire off the thread again.