# How can an app display a banner ad on the user's homescreen?

Tags: android, exploit

One of the apps on my phone is showing banner ads on my homescreen after the phone has been idle for some period of time. Touching outside of the ad hides the AdView. Take a look at the photo below:

[image: a busy cat]

I'm not sure which specific app is the cause. How did the developer accomplish this? How is he adding the AdView to the home screen?

Android 2.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be cause of the background service is running in the background so you view the adds in your home screen .
Please check the following documentation [Android background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159604/android-background-service)
and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: where is he injecting the AdView into though?

Comment: your add is continuously changing after some time duration
So there us a background service call time to time to call particular add server adds script. and it calles to your home screen

Comment: right, i understand there's a background service... but how is it possible to add the AdView to the home screen?

Comment: well an app on my phone is doing it some how, so there must be a way